# Multidimensional input for differential_evolution_minimize in tensorflow-probability?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I want to apply the Differential evolution algorithm to minimize an objective function that takes a multidimensional input tensor.

Here is the code so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability.python as tfp
import numpy as np
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# Create objective function
def objective_fn(x):
  return x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 

# Generate a population
population_size = 40
initial_population = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=[population_size, 2])

#optimize
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize(objective_fn, initial_population=initial_population, seed=43210)
print(optim_results.position)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Number of batches of 'then' must match size of 'cond', but saw: 40 vs. 2 [Op:Select]
```

Answer (score 0):

`differential_evolution_minimize` [expects](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/optimizer/differential_evolution_minimize) your objective function to accept a population of candidate solutions as an input, not a single candidate solution. In your code, you intend to access the first element of your candidate solution with `x[0]`, but what this actually does is getting the first 2-dimensional candidate solution out of population of 40. As a result, the output of your objective function is two-dimensional tensor, while tensorflow expects it to be 40-dimensional, hence the error.

To fix this for your simple example, you have to redefine the objective function so that it operates with tensors, for instance in this way:

```
def objective_fn(x):
    return(tf.reduce_sum(input_tensor=x**2, axis=-1))
```

Now, assuming your objective function is just a toy example to illustrate the issue, you probably still want to access elements of individual candidate solutions individually. If you really really need this, it is indeed possible by iterating through the population, but for any real-life application this will degrade performance a lot:

```
def objective_fn(x_population):
    result_numpy = [x[0].numpy() ** 2 + x[1].numpy() ** 2 for x in x_population]
    return(tf.constant(result_numpy))
```